# Guidance regarding skia library

Tags: linux, makefile, skia

I am trying to build the SKIA library with Linux:

```
https://code.google.com/p/skia/
```

I have successfully run `./gyp_skia` followed by the `make` command.

You often run `make install` after `make`. However, the SKIA library does not seem to have a `make install` option. I'm wondering how to perform the install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started exploring SKIA this week (on OSX), so I understand the learning curve.

The tools build static libraries, not shared libraries, thus it is not something that is "installed", at least not to end user machines. The provided tools build the libraries (*.a) not (*.so). The tool also build the unit tests and "SampleApp"

I found the following link helpful as well:

[Want to learn graphics using Skia on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639640/want-to-learn-graphics-using-skia-on-ubuntu)

Good luck

Comment: thanks a lot for the info. One more question? where does it install .a files . . the sample tests are running but I cannot find out the libskia.a file. DO u know the default location?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me at least.

```
[ -d depot_tools ] || git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
[ -d skia ] || git clone https://skia.googlesource.com/skia.git

export PATH="${PWD}/depot_tools:${PATH}"
cd skia
python tools/git-sync-deps
gn gen out/Release --args="is_official_build=true skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_icu=false skia_use_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_system_libwebp=false skia_use_system_zlib=false skia_use_libwebp=false extra_cflags_cc=[\"-frtti\"]"
ninja -C out/Release skia
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `skia_use_libjpeg_turbo` and `skia_use_system_libwebp` doesn't do much anymore.  better remove that completely.